# overiding createEvaluationContext of DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler

Tags: spring, security

My current code is

```
public class LPWebSecurityExpressionHandler extends DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler {


@Override
public EvaluationContext createEvaluationContext(Authentication authentication, FilterInvocation fi) {
    StandardEvaluationContext ctx = new StandardEvaluationContext();
    LPWebSecurityExpressionRoot root = new LPWebSecurityExpressionRoot(authentication, fi);
    root.setSiteServices(siteServices);
    root.setTrustResolver(trustResolver);
    root.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy);
    root.setSecurityContextAccessService(securityContextAccessService);
    ctx.setRootObject(root);

    return ctx;
}
```

But now createEvaluationContext in AbstractSecurityExpressionHandler is made final in latest version of spring-security-core. I am not sure how to custom create EvaluationContext now.

Answer (score 1):

resolved.

I should have overriden createSecurityExpressionRoot method instead. Really stupid of me.